# Targeting an element that has no id and no class

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Building an Instagram Bot to familiarize myself with puppeteer.

Trying to click on a *log in* button that has no selectors (instagram.com emulating iphone x in chrome).

The only thing that makes it unique is its text content/innerHMTL of 'Log In', and I can't find a way to target based on this. I don't trust the 5 character classes to be static.

I'm not very familiar with XPath expressions and can't seem to build one that works.

What's the best way to reliably target this button?

```
puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
})
    .then(async browser => {
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.emulate(puppeteer.devices['iPhone X']) //emulates iPhoneX
        await page.goto('http://www.instagram.com') 
        btn = await page.$x("Log In")    
    })
}
```

Comment: `//button[@disabled]` or `//button[@type='submit']` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to build text matching expressions with XPath using the [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) method.

```
const loginBtn= await page.$x('//*[contains(text(), "Log In")]')
await loginBtn[0].click()
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you, I had tried a similar solution, but didn't know that it was returning an array 


also, in case anyone else stumbles upon this thread, another problem I was having was on the goto line, the page wasn't fully loaded before looking for the button. I amended line 10 to read 

                await page.goto('http://www.instagram.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })